# Confused by Recursion Explanation in Java textbook

Tags: java, recursion

So I'm reading a textbook explanation of recursion and I'm getting confused. This is the example they use.

```
    public static void message(int n){
        if (n > 0){
            {
                System.out.println("This is a recursive method");
                message(n-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then they create a main method which calls the message method from above when n=5 and explain that the method is called 6 times. The method calls itself 5 times so the depth of recursion is 5. What I don't get is this: "Because there are no more statements to be executed after the method call, the fifth instance of the method returns control of the program back to the fourth instance. This repeats until all instances of the method return."

What do they mean by the method returns?

Comment: "returns" means the method finishes, and execution goes back to whatever called it. The method "returns" when it hits a `return` statement, or when execution gets to the bottom of the method.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks for the answer. The way they explain it the method has to climb back up all the instances it was called to finally return. This part is a little confusing to me but I get what return means now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the method ends. As the method is void, there is no actual result to  return, but you could write it like this.

```
public static void message(int n){
    if (n > 0){
        {
            System.out.println("This is a recursive method");
            message(n-1);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```